# Cron is running but not providing output data

Tags: cron

I'm trying to make my Amazon EC2 instances stop and start by a crontab. EC2 Api tools is succesfully installed. Manually it works.

The cron (which I put in with the command `crontab -e`):

```
10 * * * * ubuntu /usr/bin/ec2-stop-instances [instanceid] > /tmp/ec2.log
```

The file `/tmp/ec2.log` is created. When I use the command `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` I see the cron has actually run. I don't get any output in the `/tmp/ec2.log` file though. I have set all the Amazon variables needed.

Even if I on purpose create a wrong cron, like this:

```
10 * * * * ubuntu /usr/bin/ec2-stop-instancwweqes [instanceid] > /tmp/ec2.log
```

I get no output in the file. Shouldn't there be an error? I also tried not defining the user:

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/ec2-stop-instances [instanceid] > /tmp/ec2.log
```

And direct command:

```
10 * * * * ubuntu ec2-stop-instances [instanceid] > /tmp/ec2.log
```

Can someone please help me. If I can somehow debug, I can get to the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The '>'-operator only redirects everything that is written to your stdout (check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/bash-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr). Stderr is a separate outputstream, that is why your wrong cron does not work, since it writes to stderr (a typical shell shows both stdout and stderr). To append both stderr and stdout to a file, use '&>' in stead of '>'.

Now to your problem: it seems Ec2-stop-instances is not writing to stdout neither. Using

```
10 * * * * ubuntu /usr/bin/ec2-stop-instances [instanceid] &> /tmp/ec2.log
```

should fix your problem.

Another way to write is, is to redirect stderr (usually stream 1) to where stdout (usually stream 1) goes by appending 2>&1 to your construct:

```
10 * * * * ubuntu /usr/bin/ec2-stop-instances [instanceid] > /tmp/ec2.log 2&>1
```

Comment: The first way of redirecting both stderr and stdin will fail because `&>` is a bashism. The shell for cron jobs (unless modified using the `SHELL` variable in `/etc/crontab`) is `/bin/sh`. On an Ubuntu system this will be the POSIXly correct `dash` shell.